# SQL difficulty with COUNT and SUM in same query

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to count the number of customers we have and also get a sum total of the number of times books have been ordered by any customer. Our application runs on `SQL Server 2014`.

```
CustomerName is a NVARCHAR.

BookOrdered is a BIT.
```

Both fields are in the same table named Customers.

```
myQuery = "SELECT COUNT (CustomerName), SUM (BookOrdered = 1) " & _
          "FROM Customers"
```

The browser displays the error: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

This works when we run our application on `MS Access`, but we encounter errors when running it on `SQL Server`.

Comment: What does SUM (BookOrdered = 1) mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change to:

```
SELECT COUNT (CustomerName), 
       SUM (CASE WHEN BookOrdered = 1 THEN 1 ELSE O END)
FROM Customers
```